# Using a for loop to update with a class method - not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, class

I'm trying to create an array of objects with a "Node" class constructor. Each Node should have an array containing neighbouring nodes. When I use a for loop to iterate through each Node to add neighbours, it triggers the class method, but the Node object fails to update.

Here's a contrived/simplified version of what I'm doing:

```js
export default class Node {
    neighbours: Node[];
    addNeighbours: (thisNode: Node) => void;
    constructor() {
        this.neighbours = [];
        this.addNeighbours = function (thisNode: Node) {
            thisNode.neighbours = []
            this.neighbours.push(thisNode)
            console.log(this.neighbours.length); // returns 1. So this is being triggered and appears to be working.
        }
    }
}

// Create an array to represent the 2D grid.
export function createArrayOfNodes(): Node[][] {
    let returnGrid: Node[][] = [
        [new Node(), new Node(), new Node()],
        [new Node(), new Node(), new Node()],
        [new Node(), new Node(), new Node()],
    ]

    // add neighbours to each Node
    for (let i = 0; i < returnGrid.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < returnGrid.length; j++) {
            const newJ = j + 1 === returnGrid.length ? 0 : j + 1
            returnGrid[i][j].addNeighbours(returnGrid[i][newJ]); // This fails to add a neighbour
            // returnGrid[i][j].addNeighbours(new Node()); // This adds a neighbour OK
        }
    }
    // returnGrid[0][0].addNeighbours(returnGrid[0][1]); // This adds a neighbour OK

    return returnGrid;
}

console.log(createArrayOfNodes) // Returns an array of Nodes, but they don't have any Nodes in their neighbour properties.
```

As per the commented out code, I can update the `neighbours` property if it's outside the `for` loop. If I'm inside the `for` loop I can update the `neighbours` property if I create a new Node, but not if I try to add a Node from the `returnGrid`. Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the following line made your code not work. Commented it out all works fine.

```js
thisNode.neighbours = [];
```

Node should look like below

```
export default class Node {
  neighbours: Node[];
  addNeighbours: (thisNode: Node) => void;
  constructor() {
    this.neighbours = [];
    this.addNeighbours = function (thisNode: Node) {
      this.neighbours.push(thisNode);
    };
  }
}
```

Actually, you could have defined the `addNeighbours` outside the constructor.

```
export default class Node {
  neighbours: Node[];

  constructor() {
    this.neighbours = [];
  }

  addNeighbours = function (thisNode: Node) {
    this.neighbours.push(thisNode);
  };
}
```

Working example,

[image: Edit TypeScript (forked)]

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you call the `addNeighbours` method you reassign the `neighbours` array of the passed `Node`. This will effectively reset the `neighbours` array of that passed `Node`.

Remove the `thisNode.neighbours = []` line.

```js
class Node {
  neighbours = [];

  addNeighbours(thisNode) {
    this.neighbours.push(thisNode)
  }
}

// Create an array to represent the 2D grid.
function createArrayOfNodes() {
  let returnGrid = [
    [new Node(), new Node(), new Node()],
    [new Node(), new Node(), new Node()],
    [new Node(), new Node(), new Node()],
  ]

  // add neighbours to each Node
  for (let i = 0; i < returnGrid.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < returnGrid.length; j++) {
      const newJ = j + 1 === returnGrid.length ? 0 : j + 1
      returnGrid[i][j].addNeighbours(returnGrid[i][newJ]);
    }
  }

  return returnGrid;
}

console.log(createArrayOfNodes());
```

Sidenote: I noticed how you declared your properties and methods on your `Node` class. You're allowed to assign properties and methods that every instance should inherit inside of the `class` scope, instead of the `constructor`.

The `constructor` can be used to assert logic and process arguments when instantiating classes.

```js
export default class Node {
  neighbours: Node[] = [];

  addNeighbours(thisNode: Node): void {
    this.neighbours.push(thisNode)
  }
}
```